# ":-( Something went wrong" error in Hotmail/Outlook.live.com

Tags: outlook.com, outlook-on-the-web

I've been able to access hotmail.com / outlook.live.com every day on this PC, but today I received the following error in Google Chrome:

[image: Image with error]

Hotmail isn't down for everyone, and I'm also able to access it through FireFox or by using an Incognito window in Chrome.

I tried clearing my cookies for just this website by doing the following:
[image: Image with browser bar]

- I first tried clearing the cache like this: I pressed F12, and then use "Clear Cache and Force Reload" by holding the Reload icon with my mouse. This didn't work.
- I then tried clearing the cookies like this: I clicked the green lock next to the https-url, went to the cookies (there were 33), and removed all of them. This didn't work either (and currently it has 20 cookies every time I try to access the page again).
- I've tried blocking and unblocking the website.
- I've also looked in Fiddle4 what happens when I browse to `hotmail.com`, which was the following:

```
Nr Result  Protocol  Host       URL                   Body  Process
1  200     HTTP      Tunnel to  outlook.live.com:443  0     chrome:1684         
2  200     HTTP      Tunnel to  mail.live.com:443     0     chrome:1684         
3  200     HTTP      Tunnel to  auth.gfx.ms:443       0     chrome:1684         
4  200     HTTP      Tunnel to  auth.gfx.ms:443       0     chrome:1684         
5  200     HTTP      Tunnel to  auth.gfx.ms:443       0     chrome:1684         
6  200     HTTP      Tunnel to  login.live.com:443    0     chrome:1684         
7  200     HTTP      Tunnel to  login.live.com:443    0     chrome:1684         
8  200     HTTP      Tunnel to  login.live.com:443    0     chrome:1684
```

It's weird that it only shows `200` results, because when I look at the Network tab of the Google Chrome F12 menu it ends with:

```
Name:       https://outlook.live.com/owa/auth/errorfe.aspx?owaError=SDServerErr;null&owaVer=null&be=null&msg=SDServerErr&reqid=null&inex=null&creqid=...&fe=null&cid=null
Status:     500
Type:       document
Initiator:  /owa/?bO=1:173
Size:       26.1 KB
Time:       45 ms
```

- I then tried clearing my entire cookies, cache, downloads, browser history, etc. for the last week. Now when I went to hotmail.com I went to the login screen, instead of the error-screen above, so I thought it was solved. When I logged in however, I get the same error again.
- I then tried the same as above, but logged in with a different hotmail account that I've used in the past for spam when creating one-time accounts. But this leads to the same error..

My network experience is pretty bad, so now I don't really know what to try next. Does anyone perhaps know what causes this issue, or better yet, how to resolve it?

PS: Yes, I came across [this similar SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/1036928/something-went-wrong-message-when-trying-to-log-in-to-hotmail-outlook-on-c), but it doesn't have any answers, and I tried what was mentioned in the comments (with the green lock).

---

EDIT: Hmm, now about 10 minutes later when I go to hotmail.com (out of habit..) it goes to `https://outlook.live.com/owa/languageselection.aspx?url=/owa/?bO%3d1` with the following screen:
[image: language & timezone page]

When I fill in the language and timezone (it's Dutch btw), it goes to the following url with error: `https://outlook.live.com/owa/lang.owa`
**The custom error module does not recognize this error.**

Which gives a `449` error when I look at the Google Chrome network tab. I've never seen this error before, but apparently it's [*449: Retry With - The server cannot honour the request because the user has not provided the required information.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Unofficial_codes)

So I now get a different error, but I still can't access hotmail through Google Chrome. I'm convinced something is wrong with the `owa`-requests, but I'm not sure what.

EDIT 2: Back to the first error again.. >.>

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had the same error, but pausing Ad-Block fixed it for me.

Comment: @ibrahim: Comments are meant to be temporary. You should have edited that information into your answer. Fortunately, Kevin has already done it for you, but the "I'm having this problem too" content of your original answer explains the downvotes. I suggest you review the [help], especially the section on [answer].

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. I followed some steps which I would like to share. Fist I uninstalled the Office application, you can also repair the Office application instead of uninstalling. After that check the applications if it is working fine, if not then disable your antivirus or firewall. Sometimes the antivirus may be blocking the Office application to run properly. Also you delete temp files by pressing the Win+R and typing %temp% over there and it will delete the temporary files from the system. In this way you can fix the [Outlook not responding](http://www.downreporter.com/blog/microsoft-outlook/fix-something-went-wrong-problem-hotmail-outlook/) error.